# Why does git rebase from remote?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a branch A, with several commits I want to squash, and from this branch has been created an other branch (B), with several commits I want also to squash.

I rebased the branch A from develop, and squashed all commits in one commit. OK.

I then try to rebase B from the A (whose SHA1 changed because of previous commit), but the window Git shows me the list of commits since the old branch A, not the squashed one.

Why ?

Comment: The window git?

Comment: Yes, command line. I have no problem on wy workstation, but that happens on a coworker's PC. So I guess it is related to the config.

Comment: On the remote? You only changed history locally

Comment: The first rebase does not affect the _other_ branch..... branches are not tied hardly.... at most, a branch knows about its upstream branch and there are no _automatic_ actions on the downstream branch if an upstream branch is changed somehow.

Comment: It's quite hard to follow what you're describing here. Could you [edit] to show the exact commands you've run, and where? (e.g. "On my computer, I ran `git rebase foo bar`; then on my colleague's computer, I ran `git rebase bar blah`) Include what output you're seeing, and what output you expected / wanted to see.

Comment: I think the word "remote" in the question title was throwing people off. Your question is unrelated to any "remote". The answer is basically "because that's how rebase works". See [knittl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77983401/184546) for a succinct solution to the problem by using `rebase --onto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening, made clearer with some graphs. Initially, you start out with 3 branches, `develop`, `A`, and `B`:

```
a-b-c               < develop
     \
      d-e-f         < A
           \
            g-h-i   < B
```

Now you run `git rebase -i develop A` (equivalent to `git checkout A && git rebase -i develop`) and squash all commits:

```
a-b-c               < develop
    |\
    | f'            < A
     \
      d-e-f-g-h-i   < B
```

`f'` is the squashed commit. Branch `B` still references the unrelated and untouched commit `i`. Since every commit keeps an (immutable) reference to its parent commit (or parent commits), the original, unsquashed commit `d`, `e`, and `f` are still reachable from `B`.

When you now run `git rebase A B` (or the equivalent `git checkout B && git rebase A`), then Git will replay all commits reachable from `B` that are not reachable from `A`. Looking at the graph it is clear that these are commits `d..i` (d, e, f, g, h, i), including the original, unsquashed commits. Consequently, you would end up with `a-b-c-f'-d-e-f-g-h-i` – but since `f'` already contains the changes of `d`, `e`, and `f`, they cannot be reapplied and will result in conflicts.

What you want to do instead is specify the upstream and new base explicitly: `git rebase --onto A f B` (interactive rebase is supported as well with `-i`). Running this command results in the following history:

```
a-b-c               < develop
     \
      f'            < A
       \
        g'-h'-i'    < B
```

or `a-b-c-f'-i'` if you decide to squash `g..i` into a single commit.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what happens : once I rebased A, the rebase of B on A considers the commits previously in A as commits of B since their common ancestor. So when I want to rebase B on A, the old commits of A appears again. I have to manually delete them in the list of commits during the rebase operation.